# Bash script to create a replica set

Tags: mongodb, bash, replication, replicaset

I am working on a replicaSet mongo in aws, my goal is to set the replica in run time with a bash script command.

my bash look like this:

```
mongo mongodb://10.0.1.100 --eval "rs.initiate( { _id : 'rs0', members: [{ _id: 0, host: '10.0.1.100:27017' }]})"
mongo mongodb://10.0.1.100 --eval "rs.add( '10.0.2.100:27017' )"
mongo mongodb://10.0.1.100 --eval "rs.add( '10.0.3.100:27017' )"
mongo mongodb://10.0.1.100 --eval "db.isMaster().primary"
mongo mongodb://10.0.1.100 --eval "rs.slaveOk()"
```

but when i log in my instance and run rs.status(), i get the error that no config could be found.

So i tried in a different way. I accessed my fresh mongo instance, and through themongo command line i inserted the var config such as:

```
var config={_id:"rs0",members:[{_id:0,host:"10.0.1.100:27017"}, {_id:1,host:"10.0.2.100:27017"}, {_id:2,host:"10.0.3.100:27017"}]};
> rs.initiate(config);
```

if i run rs.status, it works.

i would like to run the same command through a linux bash command script to initiate the config, but i cant find a solution. any help please?

Comment: was there any output from running the shell in bash?  If not, try adding `--verbose` to each line.

Comment: in my mongodb.log i have:
2020-05-11T22:34:47.109+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local voted for document at startup.
2020-05-11T22:34:47.109+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset

With or without --verbose

Comment: I meant run the `mongo` commands with `--verbose` to get output from them.  Although, if that is all there was in the mongod log, it would seem your bash script is not making the connection.

Comment: I think you are right. My bash script is not connected. Because if i access my instance and run mongo commands, i am able to add the replicas, but the bash does not. and i dont understand why is not connected. the --verbose in fact does not print anything, which prove that the bash does not fire